# 9160 port is not opened after starting cassandra

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cassandra, amazon-vpc, cassandra-2.0

I have deployed cassandra(1.2.15) with 2 nodes on redhat 6.4 ami in aws vpc. Both nodes are in private subnet. Seed node is working fine but when I started cassandra in new node my 9160 port is not opened. I have given private ip in new node and in seed node in Listen_addess and rpc_addrss option. rpc_port is 9160. Please let me now what cause this issue. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The information on the [Creating an EC2 security group](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/install/installAMISecurityGroup.html) page may help you.

Find the security group for your instance/cluster or create a new one from your EC2 Dashboard: 
   EC2 Dashboard->Network & Security->Security Groups

and setup rules to Inbound ports using the following information:

```
Table 1. Public ports
Port number Source     Description
22          0.0.0.0/0  SSH port
8888        0.0.0.0/0  OpsCenter website. The opscenterd daemon listens on this port for HTTP requests coming directly from the browser.

Table 2. Cassandra inter-node ports
Port number Source     Description
1024-65535  <Your-SG>  JMX reconnection/loopback ports. See description for port 7199.
7000        <Your-SG>  Cassandra inter-node cluster communication.
7199        <Your-SG>  Cassandra JMX monitoring port. After the initial handshake, the JMX protocol requires that the client reconnects on a randomly chosen port (1024+).
9160        <Your-SG>  Cassandra client port (Thrift).

Table 3. Cassandra OpsCenter ports
Port number Source     Description
61620       <Your-SG>  OpsCenter monitoring port. The opscenterd daemon listens on this port for TCP traffic coming from the agent.
61621       <Your-SG>  OpsCenter agent port. The agents listen on this port for SSL traffic initiated by OpsCenter.
```

For the public ports (22 and 8888) leave the Source field 0.0.0.0/0 and for the rest, enter the name of your security group, `<Your-SG`>, so that only instances in that group will participate in the rule.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. Please pull relevant portions of your link into this answer so that the information is available even if the link is not.

Answer (score 1):

You should ensure that you've opened port `9160` in the Security Group assigned to your EC2 instance.

Comment: I have already opened. In seed node its working fine.But new node its not working.